# Building Qt from source statically for Visual Studio

Tags: c++, static-libraries, static-linking, qt6

I tried hundreds of times to build Qt from source for static linking and read many Stack Overflow questions and neither of them worked for me.

How to get the static library and use it to build apps in Visual Studio
either by downloading a pre-built one or building from source?
I got overwhelmed by errors.

#### My Environment

- Visual Studio 2022 with Qt Tools addons
- Windows 10 22H2
- Python 3.11.4
- Perl
- Cmake 3.28.0-rc5
- ninja build 1.11.1

#### Edit:

I used x64 native tools for visual studio 2022 and changed pwd to Src directory.
then executed this command:

```bash
.\configure -release -static -opensource -confirm-license -prefix G:\Libraries\C++\Qt\6.6.1\Static-Build
```

Then I got this error indicating some sort of regex problm:

```
CMake Error at qtbase/cmake/QtSyncQtHelpers.cmake:144 (list):
  list sub-command FILTER, mode REGEX failed to compile regex
  "(.+/(ui_)[^/]+\.h|G:/Libraries/C++/Qt/6.6.1/Src/qtbase/src/3rdparty/zlib(/.+)?/doc/+\.h)".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  qtbase/cmake/QtModuleHelpers.cmake:901 (qt_internal_target_sync_headers)
  qtbase/cmake/QtScopeFinalizerHelpers.cmake:24:EVAL:1 (qt_finalize_module)
  qtbase/src/3rdparty/zlib/CMakeLists.txt:DEFERRED


CMake Error at qtbase/cmake/QtSyncQtHelpers.cmake:144 (list):
  list sub-command FILTER, mode REGEX failed to compile regex
  "(.+/(ui_)[^/]+\.h|G:/Libraries/C++/Qt/6.6.1/Src/qtbase/src/corelib(/.+)?/doc/+\.h)".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  qtbase/cmake/QtModuleHelpers.cmake:901 (qt_internal_target_sync_headers)
  qtbase/cmake/QtScopeFinalizerHelpers.cmake:24:EVAL:1 (qt_finalize_module)
  qtbase/src/corelib/CMakeLists.txt:DEFERRED


CMake Error at qtbase/cmake/QtSyncQtHelpers.cmake:144 (list):
  list sub-command FILTER, mode REGEX failed to compile regex
  "(.+/(ui_)[^/]+\.h|G:/Libraries/C++/Qt/6.6.1/Src/qtbase/src/3rdparty/libpng(/.+)?/doc/+\.h)".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  qtbase/cmake/QtModuleHelpers.cmake:901 (qt_internal_target_sync_headers)
  qtbase/cmake/QtScopeFinalizerHelpers.cmake:24:EVAL:1 (qt_finalize_module)
  qtbase/src/3rdparty/libpng/CMakeLists.txt:DEFERRED


CMake Error at qtbase/cmake/QtSyncQtHelpers.cmake:144 (list):
  list sub-command FILTER, mode REGEX failed to compile regex
  "(.+/(ui_)[^/]+\.h|G:/Libraries/C++/Qt/6.6.1/Src/qtbase/src/3rdparty/libjpeg(/.+)?/doc/+\.h)".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  qtbase/cmake/QtModuleHelpers.cmake:901 (qt_internal_target_sync_headers)
  qtbase/cmake/QtScopeFinalizerHelpers.cmake:24:EVAL:1 (qt_finalize_module)
  qtbase/src/3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeLists.txt:DEFERRED


CMake Error at qtbase/cmake/QtSyncQtHelpers.cmake:144 (list):
  list sub-command FILTER, mode REGEX failed to compile regex
  "(.+/(ui_)[^/]+\.h|G:/Libraries/C++/Qt/6.6.1/Src/qtbase/src/3rdparty/freetype(/.+)?/doc/+\.h)".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  qtbase/cmake/QtModuleHelpers.cmake:901 (qt_internal_target_sync_headers)
  qtbase/cmake/QtScopeFinalizerHelpers.cmake:24:EVAL:1 (qt_finalize_module)
  qtbase/src/3rdparty/freetype/CMakeLists.txt:DEFERRED


CMake Error at qtbase/cmake/QtSyncQtHelpers.cmake:144 (list):
  list sub-command FILTER, mode REGEX failed to compile regex
  "(.+/(ui_)[^/]+\.h|G:/Libraries/C++/Qt/6.6.1/Src/qtbase/src/3rdparty/harfbuzz-ng(/.+)?/doc/+\.h)".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  qtbase/cmake/QtModuleHelpers.cmake:901 (qt_internal_target_sync_headers)
  qtbase/cmake/QtScopeFinalizerHelpers.cmake:24:EVAL:1 (qt_finalize_module)
  qtbase/src/3rdparty/harfbuzz-ng/CMakeLists.txt:DEFERRED
```

The error is a lot more than this, but it's the same error repeated for other packages I think

Any help with that?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you've tried and any specific problems/errors encountered.  Sorry, but as it stands currently the question provides no useful information.

Comment: Why do you waste your time? Why not use `.\vcpkg install qt ?

Comment: `x64-windows-static` triplet in vcpkg

Comment: I have no idea what is that? I'm actually new to the concept of linking and package management

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the cause of this error and fixed it
The main cause was because the path to Src directory contained some characters which in my case was **(+)** from word **C++** and that made some regex don't work.

Comment: Thank you for that. I had the same issue and moving it out of my c++ folder fixed it!